# Select a directory in vim and use it's name in function call

Tags: vim, file-browser

Inside a vim function I would like to have the user select a directory (instead of writing its name), I guess using :Explore, then get the filename of that directory and pass it to another function for example.

E.g. something like this

```
function! Test()
    let directory = ????
    call Test2(directory)
endfunction
```

Comment: That is not possible - there is no file selection modal dialog in Vim. You could implement it as a callback, where your directory chooser calls `Test2` on selection. However, there is no Vim functionality that lets you do that. I have never done it, but I'm thinking it might be possible in Unite.vim using `unite#custom` stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved with the [browsedir()](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#browsedir()) function:

```
function! Test()
   let initialDir = '/home/'
   let directory = browsedir('my prompt title', initialDir)
   echo "directory = ".directory
endfunction
```

Comment: That seems great! But alas I guess it only works for GUI versions. It won't work in my setup (terminal) where has("browse") returns 0